# Parse: Unauthorized in REST API

Tags: java, rest, parse-platform, jersey-2.0

I'm trying to send a push notification from my Java code consuming the Parse REST API with Jersey.

```
    Client client = Client.create();

    WebResource webResource = client.resource("https://api.parse.com/1/push");

    //My real id instead of XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX    
    webResource.header("X-Parse-Application-Id", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");

    //My real key instead of XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX 
    webResource.header("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");

    Map<String, Object> postData = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    postData.put("channels", Arrays.asList("")); //Broadcast notification

    Map<String, String> notificationData = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    notificationData.put("alert", "This is a notification");

    postData.put("data", notificationData);

    //Convert POST data to String
    String postDataAsStr = "";
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        postDataAsStr = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(postData);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ClientResponse response = webResource
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .post(ClientResponse.class, postDataAsStr);
```

POST data is like:

```
{"channels":[""],"data":{"alert":"This is a notification"}}
```

But I am getting:

> {"error":"unauthorized"}

Comment: If you use "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" as your API key it's obvious why you get the error. If you wanted to hide your real key with XXX you should clarify this in question.

Comment: Edited -.-" Now it is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. I have added the headers this way:

```
 ClientResponse response = webResource
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .header("X-Parse-Application-Id", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
                .header("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
                .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .post(ClientResponse.class, postDataAsStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to add "Authorization" header as well.

```
webResource.header("Authorization", String.format("Negotiate %s", createTicket())
```

createTicket() implementation depends on your authorization method.